# Is there a standard symbol for denoting a chapter in a citation?

Tags: symbols, citation, reference, iconography

When citing like [Source, ch.number], is there a particular symbol that could or should replace the "ch." abbreviation?

Comment: Why would there be? There are abbreviations...

Comment: @Lambie perhaps because there is such a mark for a section and a paragraph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**.  The standard abbreviations are *Ch.* and *Chap.*

…or at least, if there is such a symbol, [Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/charindex.html) doesn’t know about it yet — and Unicode is pretty comprehensive, including characters as diverse as the inverted interrobang ⸘, biohazard sign ☣, and snowman ☃, not to mention the [Shavian alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavian_alphabet) and much, much, much more.

Comment: Ugh. They should have got a typographer to proofread their sketches of the alphabet. It’s utterly unreadable, the letters are much too thin, too vertical and too similar. (“· ”).

Comment: It can also be Chpt.

Answer (score 3):

The section symbol § when handwritten is sometimes drawn as an S with a circle around the middle. One of my mathematics professors similarly denoted a chapter as a C but with the circle on the middle of the C on the left side. I like it and use it myself in notes. I found this SE thread by searching to see if this is a standard symbol or if he just invented it.

Though I think it looks good it doesn't make as much sense to use it on a C, since the original symbol is a digraph of two S characters. Perhaps one could make a sufficient digraph of stacked C characters that would work nicely. I don't think it would flow as well as the section symbol though.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen lawyers use the section symbol, **§**, to denote sections of a document that would be chapters in book form, but I'm not sure if it's entirely applicable to your situation.

Comment: At least in some technical writing, a section is typically a subdivision of a chapter; so while § is used for sections, they are specifically different from chapters.

Comment: The U.S. legal code is generally referenced by _title_ and _section_, the latter indicated by section symbol (§).  In the U.S. Code, the sections are combined into _chapters_ within a title, but the chapter number is not explicitly cited, and so no abbreviation is used for it.  The size of a section can vary from a single sentence to a very large number of pages.  See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Code#Organization) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any standard symbols I know of.

Personally, I like to use the [Ĉ character](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%88) from Esperanto orthography, because it represents the "ch" sound, which matches the "ch." abbreviation.

Answer (score -2):

ß is the symbol that lawyers use for chapter

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be better if you could include any reference/research that can support your answer. I would advise you to take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.